# How to install Magento 2.4.5 on Localhost

Tags: magento2

How to install Magento 2.4.5 on localhost with and without sample data

Comment: Can you please tell us that your magento 2.4.5 is running fine or not. I want to use Magento 2.4.5 for my site?

Comment: @RanaZain , It is working fine and also it have some additional features as well, The only problem I have arrived that is Magento 2.4.5 use php 8.1 so some old extensions giving errors of depracated functionality like strpos(), explode(), implode() etc to i have to apply empty checks on these kind of functions otherwis everything is working fine !!

Comment: You upgraded from 2.4 to 2.4.5?.  Actually I have the extensions develop on the 2.4.4, so how much we have to work on the 2.4.5?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to have problems with displaying category views as Elasticsearch or Opensearch is required.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/search/overview-search.html

As a workaround you can install local Elasticsearch or better us use the free period at elastic.co

After you have set up your cluster commands look like:

cd ~/home/www/magento2/

## install composer

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

## check PHP Module / Version

```
php -m
php -r 'phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);'
php -V
```

## check PHP Memory (2G)

php -i | grep "memory_limit"

## check mysdql

mysql -V

## create a db in MysQL

## install magento

composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.5

bin/magento setup:install 
--cleanup-database 
--base-url-secure=https://magento2.local 
--base-url=https://magento2.local 
--db-host=localhost 
--db-name=magento2 
--db-user=m2 
--db-password='xxxxxx' 
--admin-firstname=John 
--admin-lastname=Foo 
--admin-email=webmaster@foo.com 
--admin-user=Admin 
--admin-password=demo2022 
--use-rewrites=1 
--use-secure=1 
--language=de_DE 
--currency=EUR 
--timezone=Europe/Berlin 
--elasticsearch-host=https://foo.es.eu-west-1.aws.found.io 
--elasticsearch-port=9243 
--elasticsearch-enable-auth=true 
--elasticsearch-username=elastic 
--elasticsearch-password='xxxxxx'

## Run after install

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento indexer:reindex

## disable 2-Way aut

bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento cache:flush

## Magento 2.4 must have Elastic - else Caterory dont show products

bin/magento setup:install --enable-modules=Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch7,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch

FYI: you may evaluate MAMP Pro. It saves you hours of time.

Good Luck

Andy

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Visit the Link and download Magento 2.4.5 [Click Here](https://magefan.com/blog/download-magento-245-zip-archive)

**Step 2**

Go to the magento root folder, open terminal and paste the following command

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url="http://localhost/m245/" \
--db-host="127.0.0.1" \
--db-name="m245" \
--db-user="root" \
--db-password="root" \
--admin-firstname="admin" \
--admin-lastname="admin" \
--admin-email="admin@admin.com" \
--admin-user="admin" \
--admin-password="admin123" \
--language="en_US" \
--currency="USD" \
--timezone="America/Chicago" \
--use-rewrites="1" \
--backend-frontname="admin" \
--elasticsearch-host="127.0.0.1:9201"
```

**Step 3**
Now run Magento Commands

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

now hit the url in the browser **http://localhost/m245/pub/**

If your's CSS and JS not loaded maybe this is the issue of having incomplete base url to resolve this go to the database and search for the table **core_config_data** now find the path like **web/unsecure/base_url** change it's value to **http://localhost/m245/pub** now flush the cache and reload the broswer your magento will be installed successfully.

**If you want to install Sample Data run the following Command**

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

for getting access keys follow the link [Get your Authentication Keys](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html)

Now run below commands again

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

After these steps Magento will be installed successfully with Sample Data as well.